# Splitting a string with interpolation passed to system to multiple lines

Tags: string, perl

I am executing a command using `system`:

```
system("keytool -exportcert -rfc -alias  client -file /foo/bar/certificate.pem -keystore  $keystorepath -storepass \$(cat /foo/bar/password ) -v");
```

This works but I want the string command to be mulitple lines for readability.
I tried

```
my $cmd = qq {
keytool 
-exportcert 
-rfc -alias  client 
-file /foo/bar/certificate.pem 
-keystore  $keystorepath 
-storepass \$(cat /foo/bar/password ) -v
};
system($cmd);
```

but I am getting errors now.
Errors:

```
Use "keytool -?, -h, or --help" for this help message
Use "keytool -command_name --help" for usage of command_name.
Use the -conf <url> option to specify a pre-configured options file.
sh: line 1: -exportcert: command not found
sh: line 2: -rfc: command not found
sh: line 3: -alias: command not found
sh: line 4: -file: command not found
sh: line 5: -keystore: command not found
sh: line 6: -storepass: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What *errors* are you getting? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @baduker: updated post with the errors

Answer (score 3):

Since you apparently need a shell in that command and thus need to keep it in a string,<sup>†</sup> can patch up the command string by joining parts

```
my $cmd = join ' ',
    qq( keytool ), 
    qq( -exportcert ), 
    qq( -rfc -alias  client ), 
    qq( -file /foo/bar/certificate.pem ), 
    qq( -keystore  $keystorepath ), 
    qq( -storepass \$(cat /foo/bar/password ) -v );
```

I've used double quoting on all strings to follow the question but that is only needed for one part (`$keystorepart` is apparently a Perl variable to be interpolated into the command).

An advantage of doing it that way is consistency. On the other hand, one may want to use interpolation only where it's needed, what makes the operation clearer

```
my $cmd = join ' ',
     q( keytool ), 
     q( -exportcert ), 
     q( -rfc -alias  client ), 
     q( -file /foo/bar/certificate.pem ), 
    qq( -keystore  $keystorepath ), 
     q( -storepass $(cat /foo/bar/password ) -v );
```

Now we don't escape the `$` in the last line as it won't be interpolated so it is carried over to the shell as is, as needed.

There are of course other ways to organize this in the source.

In the attempt shown in the question linefeeds (newlines) are inserted in that command, what is mostly not OK for a shell command: a newline, unless escaped, terminates the command-line so the shell will run a command with what it has up to the first linefeed.  Also, the `keytool` itself may not work with a multiline invocation.

---

The question update, now showing the actual error, shows that both of the above happen: firts `keytool` is run without sufficient (or any?) arguments (up to the first linebreak?), and then the rest of the line are interpreted by the shell to be commands on their own.

---

<sup>†</sup>  If there is no need for a shell it is better to avoid it, and one way to do that is to use [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system) in its list form.  For that it'd be natural to assemble the command components above in an array, much as they are listed to be joined in a string , and then run `system` with that array.

Can't do that now because of the embedded `cat` that the shell need execute but if you ever decide to slurp the file into a variable in Perl, instead of using `cat` out of the shell, then consider that change.